# Advantages and Disadvantages of C# 4.0 'dynamic' keyword?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, dynamic

I have learned and checked the advantages of `dynamic` keyword in C# 4.

Can any body tell me the disadvantages of this. Means `dynamic` vs `Var`/`Object`/`reflection` ???

Which thing is batter more. Is `dynamic` more powerful at run time??

Comment: Var/reflection is not correct. Var is implicit typed variable evaluated at compile time. Reflection on the other hand is run time evaluated. I think reflection will stand more on side with dynamic than var.

Comment: We can't really tell that what you know is sufficient without you telling us what you know.  What are the advantages?  Please add this info to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly var vs dynamic but the following SO link discuss reflection vs dynamic. Check Out : [dynamic vs Var/Object/reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646786/dynamic-lang-runtime-vs-reflection)

Answer (score 14):

One of the most interesting thing with `dynamic` keyword which you can do is : implementation of multiple-dispatch.

Here is an example of double-dispatch (a specific case of multiple-dispatch). In OOP, at runtime a particular implementation of virtual (or abstract) method is called, based on the runtime type of *one* object which is passed as `this` to the member function.  That is called single-dispatch, as the dispatch depends on the runtime type of *single* object. In double-dispatch, it depends on the type of *two* objects.

Here is one example:

```
public abstract class Base {}
public class D1 : Base {}
public class D2 : Base {}
public class D3 : Base {}

public class Test
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Base b1 = new D1();
       Base b2 = new D2();

       Method(b1,b2); //calls 1
       Method(b2,b1); //calls 1: arguments swapped!
   }

   public static void Method(Base b1, Base b2) // #1
   {
        dynamic x = b1;
        dynamic y = b2;

        Method(x,y); // calls 2 or 3: double-dispatch - the magic happens here!

   }
   public static void Method(D1 d1, D2 d2) // #2
   {
       Console.WriteLine("(D1,D2)");
   }
   public static void Method(D2 d2, D1 d1) // #3: parameters swapped 
   {
       Console.WriteLine("(D2,D1)");
   }
}
```

Output:

```
(D1,D2)
(D2,D1)
```

That is, the actual method is selected at runtime, based on the runtime type of **two** objects, as opposed to one object.