# Why c++ compiler (VS2013) chooses wrong function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, member-functions, name-lookup, name-hiding

1. First case

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   class A
   {
   public:
       virtual void Write(int i)
       {
           std::wcout << L"Write(int) is called" << std::endl;
       }
       virtual void Write(wchar_t c)
       {
           std::wcout << L"Write(wchar_t) is called" << std::endl;
       }
   };
   int _tmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
   {
       A *p = new A();
       int i = 100;
       p->Write(i);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Works perfectly.
Program outputs
*Write(int) is called*

2.Second case.
Just move first function to base class:

```
#include <iostream>
class Base
{
public:
   virtual void Write(int i)
   {
       std::wcout << L"Base::Write(int) is called" << std::endl;
   }
};
class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    virtual void Write(wchar_t c)
    {
        std::wcout << L"Derived::Write(wchar_t) is called" << std::endl;
    }
};
int _tmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    Derived *p = new Derived();
    int i = 100;
    p->Write(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Program outputs
*Derived::Write(wchar_t) is called*
But I expected "Base::Write(int) is called"
What is wrong in second case?

Comment: @hvd: I think it's a duplicate, but not of [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991143/virtual-functions-overriding-and-hiding?lq=1).

Comment: @hvd: This question does lookup through a pointer of derived type, that one through base type.  This question introduces the functions in different scopes, that one introduces them both in the base class.  That other question appears to be solely about how virtual dispatch call the most-derived overridder, and has nothing at all to do with hiding.

Comment: @hvd: Or maybe the other question puts the "bad" (interesting) behavior first.  In which case, this question actually calls the overload in the more derived class, that question calls the one in the base class.  Name hiding is not at play in the other question at all.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's convincing enough, thanks. A quick search brings up [C++ inheritance and name hiding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946364/c-inheritance-and-name-hiding) and [C++ inheritance, base methods hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823287/c-inheritance-base-methods-hidden) as possible better duplicate candidates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your compiler is right.

When you define member function in derived class, the member function with same name in base class will be *hidden*.

You can use `using` to import it into the derived class scope, make the overloading work as you expect.

```
class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    using Base::Write;
    virtual void Write(wchar_t c)
    {
        std::wcout << L"Derived::Write(wchar_t) is called" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

**EDIT**

Function overloading won't pass through different scopes. When you call `Write` on `Derived`, the member function named `Write` will be found at the `Derived` class scope, and then *name lookup* will stop, so the `Write` in `Base` will never be considered for *overload resolution*, even if the base class version is more appropriate here.

See [Name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup)

Comment: But functions have different argument's types. Why Write(wchar_t) hides Write(int)? It's correct?

Comment: @Alex See my edited answer please. This is correct behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because the programm finds a "newer" version of the function which is correct with implicit conversion, so it doesn't look for a "better" function to call in parent class.
I'd suggest : 
1) avoid overloading/redefining functions with parameters that are interchangeable.
2) If you REALLY want Derived::Write to be called, use :

```
 p->Derived::Write(i);
```