# Making this code properly polymorphic

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

I have an abstract class Parent, which has multiple children and blank functions for interacting with each of these children. Each Child overrides Parent's functions and interacts with other Childs in different ways; i.e. Child1 has different implementations for interact_with(Child1), interact_with(Child2), etc etc.

In Parent, I have a function interact_with(Parent foo). Every Child looking to interact with another Child must pass through this function first. Until now everything is good, but then we run into a problem: after some basic logic has been processed, the Child then needs to know the specific type of its parameter so it can go on and call its own overridden function. At the moment I have this:

```
Child1* child1 = dynamic_cast<Child1*>(foo);
Child2* child2 = dynamic_cast<Child2*>(foo);
Child3* child3 = dynamic_cast<Child3*>(foo);

if(child1 != nullptr){
    interact_with(child1)
}

else if(child2 != nullptr){
    interact_with(child2)
}

else if(child3 != nullptr){
    interact_with(child3)
}
```

It *works*, but it isn't a very good solution. It gets especially bad when I have so many classes. Is this indicative of flawed base design, and if so, how would I improve this?

EDIT: To clarify: I have something like this

```
//Parent is an abstract class
class Parent
{
    void interact_with(Parent* foo){
        //this is here because there is a lengthy code segment
        //that needs to be run no matter what child interacts
        //with which

        //afterwards, I need to interact with whatever foo really is
    }

    virtual void interact_with(Child1* child){*blank*};
    virtual void interact_with(Child2* child){*blank*};
    virtual void interact_with(Child3) child){*blank*};
};

class Child1 : public Parent
{
    virtual void interact_with(Child1* child){*do something*};
    virtual void interact_with(Child2* child){*do something else*};
    virtual void interact_with(Child3* child){*do something else*};
};
```

Already.

Comment: I suppose virtual methods are out of the question?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818132/difference-betwen-visitor-pattern-double-dispatch . Not strictly a duplicate, but may help your though process, as it is definitely the problem you're trying to solve (Visitor Pattern/Double Dispatch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @imreal answer using double dispatch is correct. However, the dispatches can be done using virtual member functions instead of a map and function pointers (which is actually similar to the vtable the compiler generates).

The problem is that a single virtual function will not solve the problem, because you really need a double dispatch (i.e. a virtual call regarding both objects, not just the one being called).

See the following working example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Child1;
class Child2;

class Parent
{
public:
    virtual void interact_with(Parent* other) = 0;
    virtual void interact_with(Child1* child) {};
    virtual void interact_with(Child2* child) {};
};

class Child1 : public Parent
{
public:
    virtual void interact_with(Parent* other)
    {
        other->interact_with(this);
    }
    virtual void interact_with(Child1* child)
    {
        std::cout << "Child1 - Child1\n";
    }
    virtual void interact_with(Child2* child)
    {
        std::cout << "Child1 - Child2\n";
    }
};

class Child2 : public Parent
{
public:
    virtual void interact_with(Parent* other)
    {
        other->interact_with(this);
    }
    virtual void interact_with(Child1* child)
    {
        std::cout << "Child2 - Child1\n";
    }
    virtual void interact_with(Child2* child)
    {
        std::cout << "Child2 - Child2\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Child1 c1;
    Parent* p1 = &c1; // upcast to parent, from p1, we don't know the child type
    Child2 c2;
    Parent* p2 = &c2;

    c1.interact_with(&c2); // single virtual call to Child1 - Child2
    p1->interact_with(&c2); // single virtual call to Child1 - Child2
    p1->interact_with(p2); // double virtual call to Child2 - Child1 (NB: reversed interaction)
}
```

It outputs:

```
Child1 - Child2
Child1 - Child2
Child2 - Child1
```

Note the last one is reversed. That's because to make the dynamic dispatch using virtual functions on the argument, I have to swap the `this` pointer with the argument. This is fine if these interactions are symmetric. If they aren't, then I'd suggest to create a wrapper around the most generic one swapping the `this` and the argument again.

Comment: This solution works great. Granted, I do have to create identical virtual functions for each class, but it gets rid of the ugly dynamic casting without significantly impacting the rest of the project.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Warning: this solution will break your interfaces. But don't worry, they are already broken ;)</sub>

In my opinion your design mistake is following: although all children are "equal" you pick one of them to be responsible for interactions and call a method on it (And if you want 3, 4, ..., N equal children (in an array) to interact simultaneously, which one is responsible?)

If in your application all objects are equally important and no object is responsible for interactions, you should move interactions into free overloaded binary functions:

```
void interact(Child1* a, Child1* b);

void interact(Child1* a, Child2* b);

...

void interact(Child2* a, Child1* b)
{
    interact(b, a); // if order does not matter, reuse another function 
}
```

Clearly, it won't solve the problem of boilerplate code, but at least it could help you to re-think your design and to find a better solution than double dispatch or casting.

Also, depending on functions internals, you could probably reduce writing (but not code size) easily by using template functions instead of overloaded ones.

Comment: You raise some good points. Even though interactions will always be "initiated" by one party and only one can happen at a time, I do like your approach. However, I don't think there would be much gain in changing my entire program's structure at this point, especially since, like you said, it would not particularly solve the problem of boilerplate. Function internals can differ quite significantly and order does matter, so templates would also be of limited usefulness, I think. It seems so far that sticking with my current method of casting would be the least stressful and simplest way :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using dynamic_cast<> like that is bad design like you said. You should make the function interact_with virtual like this in the declaration.

```
virtual void interact_with(Parent foo);
```

This will make the method call use the subclass's implementation of interact_with instead of the parent class's. You can then replace everything you've written with just this.

```
interact_with(foo);
```

[Here is a pretty good explanation of virtual methods.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-methods-in-c)

Comment: I apologize if I have not explained myself properly. I am already using virtual functions. In Parent, I have virtual functions for interact_with(Child) for all the children. However, regardless of what child interacts with what other child, there is some logic that has to be done first. After this, what kind of child foo is needs to be known so that the correct interact_with() can be called; if foo is really a child4 that's no problem as I have a virtual function for interacting with child4, but at that point we only know it's a kind of Parent and not what kind of child in specific.

Comment: I'm not understanding the structure of your program. Which classes do interact_with(Parent foo) belong to? Is there another function named interact_with() as well? If so which class does it belong to?

Comment: There is a parent class, and there are children. The children interact with each other child in a different way. Parent contains a function interact_with(Parent foo), along with interact_with(Child) for every child type, which are virtual and change in each implementation of child. The idea is that every child interacts with another child in a different way, but before doing so, there is some logic that needs to be done no matter what child type it is interacting with - hence interact_with(Parent foo).

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)

There are many approaches that you might take depending on your requirements. A very generic one is having a simple map of the form Key(type, type) -> Value(function) that associates an argument type pair with the function to be called.

In this case you will need a set of free functions of the type `void function(Parent*, Parent*)` (one for every combination you need) and a map of the type `std::unordered_map<std::pair<TypeId, TypeId>, FunctionType>` where `TypeId` is some form of type identifier with value semantics.

Then you do the dispatch at runtime:

```
if(map_.find(make_pair(type1, type2)) != map_.end())
    map_[make_pair(type1, type2)](obj1, obj2);
```

Not before registering each function:

```
map_[make_pair(type1, type2)] = func12;
map_[make_pair(type2, type3)] = func23;
....
```

Comment: I learned something new today with double dispatch. However, it seems like it would be overkill in my particular case, especially considering the large number of combinations - alternatively, keeping my current method, all I need to do is add one cast/else if statement per class. At that point, I may as well do something like what Drop suggested.