# How to query into a JSON getting using LINQ?

Tags: c#, json, linq, asp.net-core, linq-to-json

> JSON

```
{
  "count": 3,
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "AAAAAAAAAAAAA",
      "description": "test1",
      "name": "name1"
    },
    {
      "id": "BBBBBBBBBB",
      "description": "test2",
      "name": "name2"
    },
    {
      "id": "CCCCCCCCCCCC",
      "description": "test3",
      "name": "name3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a code in my solution retrieving from a LIST api and giving the JSON above.
How can I use a LINQ to retrieve specific values? (e.g) I need to select `name1` and I will get the `id`,`description`,`name` values.

I am using a `dynamic` variable in my code:

`dynamic json = JObject.Parse(client.GetString().Result);`

I'd been tinkering with other online guides the past few hours. However, can't get the result right.

Please help.

Comment: why are you using `dynamic` here ? Since you already know the structure of your JSON, then you should create a Type for it.

Comment: im using dynamic for shorter code lines and using core. But im still new to this. I'll only use the values once, CMIIW so I think its not good to make another object?

Comment: I've never seen **anyone** using `dynamic` *for shorter code lines*

Comment: @Hexxed : yes you should not use `dynamic` in this case, and create a proper type here. With a strongly typed language like C#, that's the way to go. The rationale behind adding `dynamic` in the language was to allow calls that could return non-determined structures / types, for instance calls to external DLL / COM things. You want to use it only if you are really stuck otherwise.

Comment: I do agree with @Pac0, there's no need to use dynamics here, given that you already know the structure of the json string. Don't use dynamics unless you have a very good reason to do it. Check [Advantages and Disadvantages of C# 4.0 'dynamic' keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203347/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-c-sharp-4-0-dynamic-keyword)

Answer (score 4):

One solution would be to deserialize your JSON string into C# objects and then use Linq to get a specific object.

C# class definitions:

```
public class Content
{
    [JsonProperty("count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public List<Value> Values { get; set; }

    public Content()
    {
        Values = new List<Value>();
    }
}

public class Value
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Deserializing and getting the object:

```
string json = @"{
""count"": 3,
""value"": [
  {
    ""id"": ""AAAAAAAAAAAAA"",
    ""description"": ""test1"",
    ""name"": ""name1""
  },
  {
    ""id"": ""BBBBBBBBBB"",
    ""description"": ""test2"",
    ""name"": ""name2""
  },
  {
    ""id"": ""CCCCCCCCCCCC"",
    ""description"": ""test3"",
    ""name"": ""name3""
  }
]
}";


Content content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Content>(json);

Value value = content.Values.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("name1", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: this will work like a charm, however I only using the JSON value once and dispose of it. is making C# objects more efficient than using other `dynamic` solutions?

Comment: @Hexxed I don't know which solution is the most performant, you'd need to run some benchmarks to check that. For such a simple json string I'd say it won't make much difference

Comment: @Hexxed - *is making C# objects more efficient than using other dynamic solutions?* - https://stackify.com/top-11-json-performance-usage-tips/ suggests to *Use pre-defined typed classes* for faster performance.  That being said, see also https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/  See also [How does having a dynamic variable affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7478387) which indicates that using `dynamic` always has a performance penalty, which possibly might be small.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can create a class to represent a client:

```
public class Client
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

With this class, you can use `JObject.Parse` (as you're already doing) to parse the JSON into something that can be queried, use `SelectToken` to pull out the `value` array and then use `ToObject` to convert that to a list of `Client`s. Here's what that looks like:

```
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json_source);
var jsonObjectValue = jsonObject.SelectToken("value");
var clients = jsonObjectValue.ToObject<List<Client>>();
```

Once you've got your `clients` variable, you can use a simple LINQ statement to find the one that is `name1`:

```
var clientWithName1 = clients.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "name1");
```

In this case, `clientWithName` will be `null` if no such client was found.

Here's a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qTPlYJ) that demonstrates a complete solution.

Comment: I like this solution more. Just to add my two cents: jsonObject["value"] is a JArray already, so we can save a variable, and turns out to this: `var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json_source);
var clients = (jsonObject["value"]).ToObject<List<Client>>();`

Comment: Thanks for the input, @WalterAgile. You could even go as far as this: `var clients = JObject.Parse(json_source)["value"].ToObject<List<Client>>();`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Create an object Client that has properties id, description and name. Deserialize the json into a list of these objects.

```
List<Client> clients = JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<Client>>(json_source);
string desc = clients[0].description;
```

Comment: And then `clients.First[OrDefault](c => c.name == "name1");`

Comment: @KirkLarkin that's right, it should be an object with a list of Clients as written in RuiJarimba's answer. Still, the idea to deserialize to a proper type instead of `dynamic` is what makes it easier to use Linq afterwards

Comment: This is not the right answer - you cannot assume that the object with `name1` will be always the first one in the array, you need to query the deserialized array, as already mentioned by @Rafalon

Answer (score -1):

Apparently with fiddling with my code I found an answer for myself.
Thanks for to the ones trying to help me for giving me ideas.

```
var requestWorkProcess = await client.GetStringAsync("my url");
var workProcessId = JObject.Parse(requestWorkProcess)["value"].Children<JObject>().FirstOrDefault(o => o["name"].ToString() == workProcess).GetValue("id");
```

Comment: Not a downvoter, but this answer would not be the recommended way. It seems you are using everything in your power to circumvent any type safety provided by the language.