# call base class method *WITHOUT* using override

Tags: c#, subclass

I'm trying to figure out how to do something with c# that I've noticed in particular the Unity 
engine does. it seems like some form of implementation or subclassing but as I don't have the source I don't know.

in Unity all of the scripts do like this:

```
class someclass : MonoBehavior
{
}
```

now there is a list of functions you can use that the engine via this MonoBehavior calls in your classes such as

```
void OnGUI()
{
  so something here
}
```

so if you have say 5 scripts that all contain the OnGUI function it gets called in all 5 scripts

I want to implement this type of thing myself but I can't figure this out.

How do you write a Base class or Implementation or whatever this is that calls pre-defined functions in your sub classes but does not *require* the subclass to the functions and without having to use override in them ?

here is an example source file from unity Engine:

```
public class EnemyAttack : MonoBehaviour {
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        AttackTimer = 0;
        CoolDown = 2.0f;
     }
     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {
         if (AttackTimer > 0) AttackTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
         if (AttackTimer < 0) AttackTimer = 0;

         if (AttackTimer == 0){
             Attack();
             AttackTimer = CoolDown;
          }
    }
}
```

that code works perfectly and then engine calls start at first startup (single call) and calls Update *every* frame notice absolutely NO override is in that code anywhere

it sems to be some sort of event system but I can't find anything on google that describes how to do this.

Comment: Please update your title with your sprcific problem.. Read [ask]

Comment: Sounds like you could be looking for abstract classes with virtual methods.

Comment: I don't quite understand what your problem is. If you don't understand oop, I suggest you read some tutorials.

Comment: I have read tutorials and all all say that what this things does is impossible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want/can use the `override` keyword you could do this by using Reflection (possibly using the `dynamic` keyword)

The base class 'simply' searches the derived class for specific signatures/attributes and invokes the methods.

If you would write this yourself consider caching the result of the reflection (or use the `dynamic` keyword that might do the caching for you) and test whether you still get the performance you are after. Reflection can be very slow. See this question too: [Dynamic Lang. Runtime vs Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646786/dynamic-lang-runtime-vs-reflection)

Example:

```
class TheBehavior
{
    public void Act()
    {
        dynamic derived = this;
        try
        {
            derived.Foo(42);
            derived.Foob(43);
        }
        catch (RuntimeBinderException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method call failed: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}

class TheDerived : TheBehavior
{
    public void Foo(int bar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bar: " + bar);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TheBehavior behavior = new TheDerived();
        behavior.Act();
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @CodeCaster - The question is about an existing library, and the code in the question does not override any existing base class methods.

Comment: OP says: _"I want to implement this type of thing myself but I can't figure this out."_

Comment: @CodeCaster - The question asks how to do it without using `override`.

Comment: wether it smells or not Unity Game engine does it and I want to do the same thing but every tutorial I find including msdn says you have to use override but yet unity does not so its perplexing me

Comment: @BrierMay - I added to my answer. Although the code given by Lee is correct it might prove to be too slow. Consider using the `dynamic` keyword so the Dynamic Language Runtime is able to cache the results of the reflection.

Comment: @BrierMay as this answer states it is possible. However you really need to think twice wheter you want to use reflection or `dynamic`, it should only be used as last resort. One of the advantages of OO is that you have compile-time checking of your inheritance and method call structure.

Comment: I've been using normal events and delegates but I was hoping for something more like the style of Unity where I could simply do like OnConnected as I have one script running lidgren and sending events down to other ones guess I'll stick to plain events and delegates

Comment: Yes, that is a very valid and type safe way.

Comment: the reason I was looking for doing it without using override is because I have a bas network class using lidgren and as messages of certain types come in I need to pass it off to anywhere from 1 to 30 scripts so they can't override it they just need to have their version called on all of them in succession.

Comment: I like the way unity does it by having the base class just call subclass methods instead of the networkmanager.event += somefunction style

Answer (score 1):

Since it's not using virtual methods, the most likely method is using reflection. The `MonoBehavior` class will reflect over its subclasses and search for methods with names which match the right pattern:

```
public class MonoBehavior
{
    private void InitSubclass()
    {
        var methods = new[] { "OnGUI", "OnLoad" }; //etc
        foreach (string methodName in methods)
        {
            MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
            if (method != null)
            {
                method.Invoke(this, new object[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do you write a Base class or Implementation or whatever this is
>   that calls pre-defined functions in your sub classes but does not
>   require the subclass to the functions and without having to use
>   override in them ?

From what I understand, those are simply [`virtual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) methods. The base class might define some base implementation, but doesn't require derived classes to override those methods.

Comment: You would still need to `override` them

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I'm not sure to understand your comment?

Comment: in Unity engine you do NOT use overid anywhere with them

Answer (score 0):

if I'm getting what you're saying I think what you're searching for is a base class with inheritance:

```
public class BaseClass // or abstract
{
    public void foo(int x)
    {
        //your implementation
    }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public void foo(int x) : base(x)
    {
        //your implementation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `virtual` and `override`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyBaseClass ext1 = new Ext1();
        ext1.DoSomething();

        MyBaseClass ext2 = new Ext2();
        ext2.DoSomething();

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}

class MyBaseClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomethingBase();
    }

    protected virtual void DoSomethingBase()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomethingBase");
    }
}

class Ext1 : MyBaseClass
{

}

class Ext2 : MyBaseClass
{
    protected override void DoSomethingBase()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Overridden DoSomethingBase");
    }
}
```

The `Ext1` class does not override the base's behaviour, so `DoSomethingBase()` from the base class is used. `Ext2` does override the base method, so the overridden method gets called. This code prints:

> ```
> DoSomethingBase
> Overridden DoSomethingBase
> ```

The `MyBaseClass` class can also be marked as `abstract` to prevent instantiation of the base class itself.