# Sharing of Property in a DTO using Category attribute c#

Tags: c#, model, dto, system.componentmodel

I'm working on Employee Model, it contains all the information about the Employee already I posted the same in [How to use the DTO efficiently based on Scenario in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083024/how-to-use-the-dto-efficiently-based-on-scenario-in-c-sharp). How could I share the single property for the multiple groups using Category attribute c#.

For Example:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
}
```

I'm having the following four methods for fetching records of Employee

```
public Employee GetEmployeeName(int id)
{
    // The return should contain only FirstName, MiddleName and LastName. 
    // The rest of the properties should be non-accessable (i.e., Private)
}

public Employee GetEmployeeContacts(int id)
{
    // The return should contain only EmailAddress, HomePhone and MobilePhone. 
    // The rest of the properties should be non-accessable (i.e., Private)
}

public Employee GetEmployeeNameEmail(int id)
{
    // The return should contain only FirstName, MiddleName, LastName and EmailAddress. 
    // The rest of the properties should be non-accessable (i.e., Private)
}

public Employee GetEmployee(int id)
{
    // It should return the entire Employee object
}
```

How could I achieve this? could you please any one help in this regards.

Comment: Create a EmployeeNameDto, EmployeeContactsDto etc... only with the properties you want share. In your method instance dto and set values and return the dto

Comment: @ArDumez: Could you please explain in briefly...

Answer (score 0):

A sample, this is the common use for DTO:

```
public class EmployeeNameDto
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public EmployeeNameDto GetEmployeeName(int id)
{
    Employee emplpoyee = employeeRepository.Find(id):
    return new EmployeeNameDto() {
      EmployeeId = emplpoyee.EmployeeId,
      FirstName = emplpoyee.FirstName,
      MiddleName = emplpoyee.MiddleName,
      LastName = emplpoyee.LastName
    };
}
```

Or

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; 
      set {
        if (condition == false)
          throw new Exception(" is Read Only !")
      }
    }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I asked the question How to share the property using `Category attribute - c#`. But in the answer section shows a new DTO for Name section. - It's not suit for my question.

Comment: I have edit my answer, Have you an sample how you want use Category attribute ?

Comment: Kindly refer the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute_properties(v=vs.110).aspx for more information about `Category attribute`