# Performance dynamic vs Reflection

Tags: c#, performance, linq, dynamic, reflection

I have the following possibilities to retrieve values in a list:

using reflection:

```
foreach (var item in items) {
  var property=item.Fields[fieldName].GetType().GetProperty("Id");
  var value=property.GetValue(item.Fields[fieldName]);
  if (value==searchValue) {
      filtered.Add(item);
   }
}
```

using dynamic:

```
foreach (var item in items) {
   dynamic itemProperty=item.Fields[fieldName];
   if (itemProperty.Id==searchValue) {   
      filtered.Add(item);
   }
}
```

Both loops do the same. They filter the IEnumerable (or List) by Field[fieldName] which can be of different types but which all contain a int-property called "Id".

I wonder, which one would have a better performance.
In addition: Would changing one of those to a LinQ-Query increase the performance?

Comment: `dynamic` also uses reflection, but not in such a crude way you do in your first example. So I'd suspect dynamic will be faster here. Of course you could have just measured that yourself.

Comment: there's a much simpler way to approach this kind of scennario - add an `interface IHasId { int Id {get; } }` and have your types implement it (which because of implicit interface implementations usually just means adding `: IHasId` to each)... then `foreach(IHasId item in items) { if (item.Id == searchValue) { ...} }`

Comment: Why don´t you simply try it out on a big enough collection? Simply *measure* it, e.g. using `StopWatch`. And also have in mind not to do [premature optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization). Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646786/dynamic-lang-runtime-vs-reflection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *easiest* way to do this IMO is to define an interface that has an `int Id {get;}` property and have your types implement it. Then code to the interface. If your existing code is generic you might even be able to add a`where T : IYourInterface` constraint, but you can cast to `IYourInterface` either way (assuming `T` actually does implement the interface).

If interfaces aren't an option:

Reflection and `dynamic` both have overheads; `dynamic` has better optimization (re-using a cached strategy).

If your `items` list is strongly typed to a specific `T` (where `T` is unknown here), then you can *possibly* further optimize this concept using LINQ expressions to compile delegates:

```
static class IdFetcher
{
    public static int Fetch<T>(T item) => IdFetcher<T>.Fetch(item);
}
static class IdFetcher<T>
{
    public static int Fetch(T item) => fetch(item);
    static readonly Func<T, int> fetch;
    static IdFetcher()
    {
        var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
        fetch = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(
            Expression.PropertyOrField(p, "Id"), p).Compile();
    }
}
```

Then just use `IdFetcher<T>.Fetch(obj)` or `IdFetcher.Fetch(obj)` (the first is more direct; the second is useful for anonymous types where you can't specify the `T`)

Other than that: if you want to know which is faster: time them (for large numbers of iterations).