# C# - Polymorphic method selection from base type

Tags: c#, reflection, polymorphism

Imagine there is some kind of factory method called `GetInstance()` that builds a class and returns a base instance;

```cs
abstract class BaseClass { }

class Type1 : BaseClass { }

class Type2 : BaseClass { }

BaseClass GetInstance()
{
    // returns either Type1 or Type2 instance
}
```

I want to execute one of two methods that takes the concrete class instance as a parameter, not the base class

```cs
void DoSomething(Type1 instance)
{
    // do something with type 1 instance
}

void DoSomething(Type2 instance)
{
    // do something with type 2 instance
}
```

The ugly way of doing it, that clearly breaks the open-closed principle, is to just iterate through all the possible types, calling the appropriate method

```cs
void GetAndInvokeBad()
{
    BaseClass instance = GetInstance();
    
    // Sucky way of selecting the right polymorphic method
    switch (instance)
    {
        case Type1 t1instance:
            DoSomething(t1instance);
            break;
        case Type2 t2instance:
            DoSomething(t2instance);
            break;
    }
}
```

A more generic way of doing it would be to use reflection to look up all the methods that can take the class instance physical type

```cs
void GetAndInvokeGood()
{
    BaseClass instance = GetInstance();

    var method = GetType().GetMethods()
        .Where(m => m.Name == "DoSomething")
        .First(m => m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == instance.GetType());

    method.Invoke(this, new object[] {instance});
}
```

I'm just wondering, is this a good pattern? Is there a better and more recognised way of switching on the child type rather than using reflection?

Comment: Why not overload `GetInstance` to return the specific types?

Comment: Look for "Double Dispatch in C#"

Comment: The strategy pattern lets you switch between cases without breaking the open/close principle.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay C# does not support return type covariance - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5709191/1069178

Comment: @Steztric Overload not override. It was a poor choice of words though; I simply meant use separate methods returning the specific types, overloaded or otherwise.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay understood. If I did that it would fail to be a factory pattern because the caller would need to know which subclass to instantiate and call the appropriate method. It would also require switching on types, which is exactly what I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use the strategy pattern. (don't take this example as a literal example as I wrote it from the top of my head and I might have some of the syntax wrong without checking it in an IDE, it gives you the gist though.)

```
public class InstanceHandler {
    //Dependency inject or load at runtime.
    private IEnumerable<BaseClass> _declaredTypes;

    public void DoSomething(object obj) {
        var result = _delcaredTypes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsType(obj));
        if(result == null) {
            throw new NotSupportedException($"The type '{obj}' is not supported.");
        }
        result.DoSomething(obj);
    }
}

public abstract class BaseInstance() {
    public abstract bool IsType(object type);
    public abstract void DoSomething(object type);
}

public class A : BaseInstance {
    public override bool IsType(object type) {
        return true; //Logic to check if type is matching instance.
    }

    public override void DoSomething(object type) {
        var castType = (ExpectedType) type;
        //Do Something.
    }
}
```

Comment: I see! That's great. Is it possible to make this contravariant? For example, define `BaseInstance<in T> where T is BaseClass`, then the abstract method can be `public abstract void DoSomething<T>(T type)` and then A could be `class A : BaseInstance<Type1>` and the method can be `public override void DoSomething(Type1 type)`. This would overcome the need to cast in the method.

Comment: @Steztric It might be possible if you have a play around with it however, as I see it, you'd have an issue storing the declared types with different generic types within the same collection. Maybe you can create a wrapper around the types to store them within the same collection.

Comment: good point. If I did that then I can't store these handlers in `_declaredTypes`

Answer (score 2):

You could also get really dirty and use `dynamic`.  Not everyone is a fan of it; I avoid it unless it's too useful for a certain scenario, and then comment it heavily.  Here, it makes for a quite clean implementation.

Using `dynamic` prevents code analyzers from inspecting that code and finding issues, so just be aware of that when considering its use.

Lastly, here's an [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4646786/3791245) about using `dynamic` for reference.

```
using System;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            dynamic instance1 = GetInstance(true); //gets Type1
            dynamic instance2 = GetInstance(false); //gets Type2

            DoSomething(instance1); //prints "Type1 did something"
            DoSomething(instance2); //prints "Type2 did something"
        }

        static BaseClass GetInstance(bool type1)
        {
            // returns either Type1 or Type2 instance
            return type1 ? (BaseClass)(new Type1()) : (BaseClass)(new Type2());
        }

        static void DoSomething(Type1 instance)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type1 did something");
        }

        static void DoSomething(Type2 instance)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type2 did something");
        }
    }

    abstract class BaseClass { }

    class Type1 : BaseClass { }

    class Type2 : BaseClass { }
}
```

If you don't want to pass around variables as `dynamic`, you can also cast to `dynamic` at the last mile, such as:

```
DoSomething((dynamic)instance);
```