# Understand invokation on dynamic objects in C#

Tags: c#, ironpython

I've got some code that takes a `PythonFunction`.

The standard way of invoking it seems to be:

```cs
engine.Operations.Invoke(myfunction, arg);
```

However, I've found experimentally that

```cs
((dynamic) myfunction)(arg)
```

Is very approximately twice as fast. I've been trying to figure out how exactly casting to `dynamic` can expose an invokable interface and where to see the code that runs under those circumstances.

Can someone point me to where in the `PythonFunction` code the implementation of `dynamic` invoke is?

Comment: Without knowing the internals of Operations.Invoke but my guess would be that it is using reflection. The difference in performance might be explained by this answer of Eric Lippert: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4649596

Comment: The thing is, the model of "It does what it would have done if the type information was there" falls down when you hit Invoke. Because you can't invoke `myfunction` without first casting to `dynamic`.